# How to sum between dates using SQL?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005

Look at the following **UPDATED** scenario (sorry that I fooled you with the un updated version - hope it will be clearer now) - it may seem simple to some people, and hopefully it is!

Explanation: Every row is a Request. Allocated is the number of people requested to an activity, total is the total amount of people for this country available for activities, and diff is... the diff between the total amount of people and Max people used.
**And "Max people used..." is what everything else hangs on.**

```
SHOULD BE:                      

COLLECTION OF REQUESTS WITH DIFFERENT START- AND END DATES

COUNTRY START DATE  END DATE    ALLOCATED   TOTAL    Max people used for this period    DIFF
China     NOV 1       NOV 2       2           5         4                                 1
China     NOV 3       NOV 4       2           5         4                                 1
China     NOV 1       NOV 4       2           5         4                                 1


MY RESULT:

COLLECTION OF REQUESTS WITH DIFFERENT START- AND END DATES

COUNTRY START DATE  END DATE    ALLOCATED   TOTAL    Max people used for this period    DIFF
China     NOV 1       NOV 2       2           5         4                                 1
China     NOV 3       NOV 4       2           5         4                                 1
China     NOV 1       NOV 4       2           5         6                                -1

(For NOV 1 to NOV 4 "Max people used..." sums ALLOCATED as 2+2+2 instead of 2+2...)
```

And here you can see how I got "MY RESULT"

```
SELECT DISTINCT Country.Country,
-- here comes the sum that doesn´t work...
SUM(Requests.[Amount of people per day needed]) AS [Max people used for this period]
FROM         Country INNER JOIN
                      Requests ON Country.CountryID = Requests.CountryID
WHERE     (Country.Country = 'China')
AND (Requests.[End date] >= @busyStartDate)
AND (Requests.[Start date] <= @busyEndDate)
GROUP BY Country.Country
```

"Max people used..." is the thing not working here - can I get that right, the rest will follow by business logic that you don´t see here :-)

**UPDATE**

Actually, I have given this up - didn´t get it to work in spite of good answers. Instead I did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140657/how-to-output-only-one-max-value-from-this-query-in-sql) (with the help of others, of course) to finally reach my goal **;-)**

Comment: Can you post the complete query, as well as the structure of the `Requests` and `Country` tables? What is the `Amount of people per day needed` column? Where do you calculate the `Diff`? I don't see that in your post.

Comment: Yes please post your query for the diff column, seeing as that is the one which doesn't work

Comment: He's asking for the SQL server to spot that `1-2 use 2`, `3-4 use 2` never overlap and so only sum one of them against `1-4 use 2`. Unfortunately I think you'll have to break this out into individual days and then run statistics across that. You might be able to manage with just the start and end days of each range - find all unique dates then sum all usages for that date across all requests.

Comment: @Rup, you´re analysis is completely right, and I hoped that I could come through _without_ break it down to individual days... but if there is no other way I have to do it "the hard way" as you propose :-(

Comment: But for the nearest future (hours) I´m hoping for someone to bring some unknown magic into this matter :-)

Comment: And, yes, the question is updated almost as Oded and Tarski wanted it to be...

Answer (score 1):

**All-in-one multiple CTE solution** (thanks Martin!)

```
with AllDates as (
  select  StartDate as [day] from Request
  union
  select  Enddate as [day] from Request),
TotalUsage as (
  select  [day], sum(allocated) as TotalAllocated
    from  AllDates
    join  Request
      on  [day] between StartDate and EndDate
    group by [day]),
MaxPerRequest as (
  select  CountryId, StartDate, EndDate, Allocated, MAX(TotalAllocated) as MaxAllocated
    from  Request
    join  TotalUsage
      on  [day] between StartDate and EndDate
    group by CountryId, StartDate, EndDate, Allocated
    )
select StartDate, EndDate, Allocated, MaxAllocated, Country.People - MaxAllocated as Diff
  from MaxPerRequest
  join Country on MaxPerRequest.CountryId = Country.CountryId
```

**Old temp-table solution**

Alas I don't think you can nest CTEs, so you'd need something like

```
with alldates as (
  select StartDate as [day] from request
  union
  select EndDate as [day] from request)
select [Day], sum(allocated) as TotalAllocated
into #TotalUsage
from alldates
join request on [Day] between StartDate and EndDate
group by [Day];
```

to build the total allocated per day for all interesting dates into a temporary table. (I can never remember which is the best temp table mechanism for SQL Server sorry - it may be better to go with a table variable, and may need to add indexes + keys either way.) You can then select max(TotalAllocated) from that for a given date range.

```
with MaxPerRequest as (
  select CountryID, StartDate, EndDate, Allocated, MAX(TotalAllocated) as MaxAllocated
    from request
    join #TotalUsage
      on [DAY] between StartDate and EndDate
    group by CountryID, StartDate, EndDate, Allocated
    )
select StartDate, EndDate, Allocated, MaxAllocated, Country.People - MaxAllocated as Diff
  from MaxPerRequest
  join Country on MaxPerRequest.CountryID = Country.CountryID

drop table #TotalUsage
```

Sorry I can't think of a simpler solution.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand what you meant by "nesting CTES". You can do `WITH T1 AS ( SELECT 1 AS id ), T2 AS (SELECT id+1 AS id2 FROM T1) SELECT * FROM T2`

Comment: Oh, excellent, thanks - I tried `with () with ()` and `with ( with () )` which didn't work and must have missed the comma syntax on the man page.

Comment: @Rup - when trying this out, there is a part I don´t understand: "MaxPerRequest.Country" - where did you get that? :-)

Comment: Error message: MaxPerRequest.Country could not be bound

Comment: Sorry I meant `CountryID` - it's meant to be `Requests.CountryId` from your query in the aggregated version. I'll fix it. I mocked up a Reqest table to test this but not a Country table so I may well have made other syntax errors here but hopefully the general structure is useful and you can see what I was trying to do.

Comment: Yep, thanks! I´ve "edited" a bit to make it possible to execute - but, now, when I think I´ve done the right things, I get the following message when executing the query: "Cannot call methods on nvarchar" - hmmm... that must be the the SUM and MAX functions, right? Probably I did something wrong then - I will make a new try in a while.

Answer (score 1):

I think the search condition you require will look something like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM MyTable AS T1
 WHERE CASE 
          WHEN @start_date > T1.start_date THEN @start_date 
          ELSE T1.start_date 
       END 
       < 
       CASE 
          WHEN @end_date > T1.end_date THEN T1.end_date 
          ELSE @end_date 
       END;
```

...but I would be making many assumptions about your data to come up with much more e.g. are you using the closed-open representation, are you using DATETIME values, etc?

Temporal database design is very difficult to get right and if your SQL DDL isn't correct then your SQL DML will be very tricky indeed. A good book on the subject is [Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/people/rts/tdbbook.pdf) by Rick Snodgrass, available as a free pdf download.

Comment: Thanks for good tip! I will check your solution - and download that book :-)

Comment: Skim read preface and chapters 1 and 2. Make sure you understand chapters 3 and 4. Chapter 5 will reveal how you should have designed your schema. You will then find your answer in chapter 6. Good luck :)